# Restful Api: User id in each repository method?

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

I am new to both .Net & RESTful services.

Here is the object hierarchy I have in the database: Users->Folders->Notes.

The API: GET /api/note/{noteid}

would get mapped to the repository call

NoteRepository::GetNote(userId, noteId)

Notice that I am passing on the userId to make sure that the note belongs to the logged in user for security purpose.

Is this the right approach? Meaning, every repository call would have the first parameter as the userId to check if the object being accessed belongs to the user.

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the User Id since the

```
GET /api/note/{noteid}
```

is indeed unique.

A valid scenario for adding the id would be:

```
GET /api/{userId}/notes
```

And then if you want a specific note you can:

```
GET /api/{userId}/notes/{noteId}
```

I would implement security at the entry level. whether the user has rights to perform a method on that specific resource. A role model approach would be fine.

Regards.

Comment: Hi Udo, I agree with you, user id is not needed as long as noteid is unique across users. What do you think however about my doubt. How to expose a list of notes? The logical would be GET /api/note/ but now is not anymore unique across users. If we do GET/api/note/<userid> now it's not anymore a parent of the note request which is also bad.

Comment: Yes, I think it makes more sense to me, since it respects the principles I've read about REST. However, as I noticed, it seems that Google and Twitter are not doing this.

Comment: Just a doubt. If we are using Basic HTTP Authentication then we wouldn't need the user id because the user id will be part of the HTTP headers. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: @goths: What would be in the header is the credentials (username and password). But then you can obtain the Id from the username. Some frameworks stores in a security context the user. So you do not need the lookup.

Comment: @stivio: The modelled the note resource. That way you do not disclose the user Id in the url. I just wanted to show an example with id.

Answer (score 2):

I would also introduce the user id in the API, because of Stateless and Cacheable constraints described in the [Wikipedia REST article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Constraints).

However, if I check [Google Tasks REST API](http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/v1/reference.html), they don't include the user id, same thing for [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api), so it seems a trend not to include the user id. If someone can shed some light I would be grateful.

**UPDATE**: Thinking more about it, if the noteid is unique across all users, there is no need to include the user id, so a GET /api/note/{noteid}  is fine.

However, the logical parent in a restful interface would be GET /api/note/ to get a list of all notes, and here I've the objection, since the list would differ according to the user requesting it, making it non cacheable.

As for your dot net part I think that passing the userid among dot net methods is perfectly fine.